# assembly code:understanding the lea command

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I found this code:

```
lea 0x10(%edi),%esi
mov %esi,0x4(%edi)
```

but I really don't understand this combination.

1. what is exactly happens on the stack on the lea-command.
2. is it not easier just to write: mov 0x10(%edi),0x4(edi%) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nothing happens to the stack.
2. It might be, but that's not a valid instruction.  `mov` supports at most one memory operand.  Anyway, your example appears to have different semantics (as mentioned by @zch below).

You can grab a copy of the [Intel Software Developers Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and read all you want about it.

Edit:  Regarding your questions "what value is written in %esi ? lea is calculation the offset? of which address?"

`esi` gets `edi + 0x10`; that's what that `0x10(%edi)` means.  `lea` stands for "load effective address".  That is, it interprets `edi` as a pointer, and increments it by 0x10, storing the result in `esi`.

Comment: It would also mean different thing. Writing value, rather then address.

Comment: 2. I see, thanks. but 1. what value is written in %esi ? lea is calculation the offset? of which address?

Comment: Ah, wait. Is it just a tricky way to simply write a 0x10 to %esi?

Comment: Not quite.  It writes `edi + 0x10` to `esi`.  The documentation I linked to has everything you need to know (except maybe translating intel syntax to at&t syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The use of `lea` vs. `mov` in x86 assembly is the same kind of thing as, in C/C++, saying:

```
char *ptr;
...
ptr = &val;
```

vs.

```
char *ptr;
...
*ptr = val;
```

`lea` *calculates* the address, `mov` (or other instructions with memory operands) *dereferences* (accesses) it.

So `lea` does in x86 assembly what's called "pointer arithmetics" in C/C++ - no memory access is involved.